# Get/Upload files using angular and .NET Core API

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I develop an angular application with a .Net Core API and I want to get images from the server and uploading to the server.

Here is my angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class FileService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  // Method to get a file
  getFile(id: number): Observable<any> {
    const idFile: number = id === null ? 0 : id;
    const requestUrl = 'api/get-image/' + idFile;
    return this.http.get(requestUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }

  // Method to upload a picture
  uploadAvatar(fileList: File[], fileName) {
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      const file: File = fileList[0];
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
      const requestUrl = 'api/upload';
      this.http.post(requestUrl, formData);
    }
  }
}
```

And my controller .NET :

```
[Route("api")]
public class FileController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public async Task Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file == null) throw new Exception("File is null");
        if (file.Length == 0) throw new Exception("File is empty");

        var filePath = Path.Combine(AppConfig.ResourcesPath + file.FileName);
        using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet("get-image/{id}")]
    [Produces("image/png")]
    public IActionResult GetFile(int id)
    {
        string path = "";
        if (id == 0)
        {
            path = AppConfig.DefaultImgEvent;
        }
        else if (id == -1)
        {
            path = AppConfig.DefaultImgUser;
        }
        else
        {
            Picture picture = _pictureDal.GetById(id);
            path = picture.Path;
        }
        var file = Path.Combine(AppConfig.ResourcesPath, path);
        _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.GetItem, "Get file {0}", file);
        return PhysicalFile(file, "image/png");
    }
}
```

For the get I have a 404 error:

> Failed to load the resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) [object% 20Blob]: 1

And for the upload I cannot get into the controller

Comment: Check that you have specified the full url for the api in your angular code i.e return this.http.get('full url', { responseType: 'blob' }); Use Postman to test the api.

Comment: You have to specify `[ApiController]` on the controller level, secondly you cannot access file as `IFormFile` in the WebApi Project. Try to convert the file into base64 string and then post to the endpoint as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try return this.http.get(requestUrl, { responseType: 'blob', params: idFile });
And your requestUrl should be just the 'api/get-image/'

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem for the get file :

```
this.fileService.getFile(this.userDetail.picture.id).subscribe((file) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    this.avatar = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
});
```

I added a sanitizer...

But for the upload file it's always the same problem, and it's not an uri problem.